# Bing Maps Reverse GeoCode by Landmark or Building Name

Tags: bing-maps, bing

Is it possible to reverse geocode by a landmark or building name using Bing Maps?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse geocoding generally refers to the process of going from a known latitude/longitude to a place description. For reverse geocoding to business/place names you should use this API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/location-recognition
From your question it sounds like you want to go from a place name to a lat/long (which is forward geocoding) for that you would use the locations API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/